# Should I always avoid force unwrapping?

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I recently started a project where there was a lot of force unwrapping being used as XCode was suggesting it as a fix whenever someone needed to unwrap an optional. Needless to say there were a lot of crashes so we had a big refactor to remove them all, in favour of optional binding, settings the properties to non-optional, nil-coalescing and allowing function to take optional values. We banned them in our coding guidelines and started using swiftlint to ensure people don't put them back in (force unwrapping is flagged as a warning when using swiftlint).

However I keep running in to situations like below where I'm 100% sure the value isn't nil (in this case we have already checked the array is not empty prior to sorting it). It feels wasteful to use `if let` and a bit weird to allow `findProvider` to accept optionals as arguments but if I leave this in swift lint will flag it, our ban on force unwrapping will have to go and I guess someone could feasibly alter this code so the `sortedParsedNumbers.first` is `nil`. What's the best thing to do here?

```
if meeting.phoneNumbers.isEmpty || Settings.prioritizeSettingsNumbers {
    return settingsNumber ?? derivedLocationNumber
}

let sortedParsedNumbers = sortParsedNumbers(meeting: meeting)
let providerMismatch = ConferenceNumberDirectory.findProvider(forNumber: sortedParsedNumbers.first!)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715568/why-to-avoid-forced-unwrapping

Comment: You can also disable swiftlint rules. You could say `//swiftlint:disable:this force_unwrapping` and add a comment why you disabled the rule there.

Comment: Any reason you aren't simply taking the `min` of `meeting`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Where do you think I should use it? The sortedParsedNumbers are `String` phone numbers. The provider is an enum that doesn't conform to `Comparable`.

Comment: Where you do the sorting, take the minimum element instead

Comment: @BallpointBen They're not regular numbers. I'm sorting the phone numbers based on the teleconference provider they belong to and the country they're used for.

Comment: Just as you can specify a closure to sort by, you can specify a closure to evaluate min/max by. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298201-min. This doesn't change the need for unwrapping, but at least you can move the unwrap closer to the source.

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks I've had a go at using that but I fear it's less readable.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180085/sorting-a-list-of-phone-numbers-by-teleconference-provider-location